# How do I store the user input as multiple entries, and then allow the user to search for the items they created?

Tags: python, crud

The user can create as many entries as they want, but I am unsure of how to save all those entries. Is it possible to use JSON for this? Also, i'm unsure of how to allow the user afterwards to search for the items they created.
By search I mean Read in CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delate)

```
def shoeDetails(self):
        theSize = input('What is the size:')
        theColor = input('What is the color: ')
        theQuantity = input('Please enter the quantity:')
        shoeDict = {'Shoe Size': theSize, 'Color': theColor, 'Quantity': theQuantity}
        print(Dict)

def dressDetails(self):
        theColor = input('What is the color:')
        theQuantity = input('What is the quantity:')
        bust = input("What is the bust size?")
        hips = input("what is the hips size:?")
        waist = input("What is the waist size:?")
        dressDict = [{'Color:': theColor, 'Quantity:': theQuantity, 'Bust Size:': bust, 'Hip Size:': hips, 'Waist Size:': waist}]
        print(dressDict)
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand. Can you please be a little more specific as to what you mean by "search"?

Comment: By search I mean READ. In the CRUD(Create, Read, Update, and Delete)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but I'll try:

```py
print("Shoe:")
theSize = input('What is the size:')
theColor = input('What is the color: ')
theQuantity = input('Please enter the quantity:')
shoeDict = {'Shoe Size': theSize, 'Color': theColor, 'Quantity': theQuantity}
#print(Dict)
print("dress:")
theColor = input('What is the color:')
theQuantity = input('What is the quantity:')
bust = input("What is the bust size?")
hips = input("what is the hips size:?")
waist = input("What is the waist size:?")
dressDict = [{'Color:': theColor, 'Quantity:': theQuantity, 'Bust Size:': bust, 'Hip Size:': hips, 'Waist Size:': waist}]
#print(dressDict)
#if you want to access bust size of dress:
print(dressDict["Bust Size"])
#if you want shoe size:
print(shoeDict["Shoe Size"])
```

Hope this is what you want.